# Why shadow is toggling in turnjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, turnjs

I can't get, why shadow of pages is toggling when page is being turned. Why this could happen?

I tried to write minimal script to reproduce the issue:
http://warp-dev.alvass.in/products/image/

Comment: Make it with more pages and see what happens.

Comment: @Havenard i tried, for first page i see the same behaviour. Perhaps there is a way to fix that? Looks very annoying :(